# Apache Tomcat configuration Issues

Tags: java, tomcat

I have just set up Java and it's packages. However,I am having problem writing 
my "hello world" java web application in my NetBeans IDE.
Apache Tomcat does not start properly and throws the exception"server port 8080 is already in use".
I will be grateful for any suggestion or solution

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat by default uses port 8080 to run. So if any other application is running on this port then tomcat will not start. Change port in server.xml file; you can put any other value like 8085.

```
           <Connector port="8080" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
           maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
           enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
           connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true" />
```

Port is specified in Connector element of server.xml.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is self explanatory. There is some other process which is still alive and use 8080 port.

In your apache conf folder, open the httpd file and look for 8080 port. Change 8080 to any port you like. You might find 8080 at two places.

You can easily change the port number in net-beans by simply moving on to `servers>tomcat and right click .. properties. and change the port to say 8084 etc...`